# @Html.Captcha no funciona correctamente

Tags: html5, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, razor, captcha

Recientemente elaboré una página que cuenta con html y razor, en ella tengo un @html.Captcha como el siguiente:

```
@Imports CaptchaMvc.HtmlHelpers
@Html.Captcha("Refrescar", "Por favor, escriba el texto de la imagen.", 5, "Is required field.", True)
```

El problema se da cuando cargo la página por primera vez, yo escribo el texto de la imagen generada correctamente pero aún así me indica que el texto está incorrecto, luego lo vuelvo a escribir y se valida correctamente.

[image: Ingreso de datos]

El resultado es un error manejado por jquery.validate:
[image: Error mostrado]

Ademas en mi archivo de jquery solamente valido lo siguiente:

```
$('form').validate({
    rules: {            
        CaptchaInputText: {
            required: true
        }
    },
    highlight: function (element) {
        $(element).closest('.form-group').addClass('has-error');
        $('#validarDatos').prop("disabled", true);
    },
    unhighlight: function (element) {
        $(element).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-error');
        $('#validarDatos').prop("disabled", false);
    },
    errorElement: 'span',
    errorClass: 'help-block',
    errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
        if (element.parent('.input-group').length) {
            error.insertAfter(element.parent());
        } else {
            error.insertAfter(element);
        }
    }
});// fin form.validate
```

Comment: tengo el mismo problema, y aun no encuentro ayuda